# Player Jump delys when you start moving and then jumping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The player delays when you start moving and then jumping, but when you are moving a bit of distance, you the jump does not delay, it only does when you start moving and then jumping.

```
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public float speed = 10;
float xMovement;
Vector2 currentPos;
Vector2 movementVecotor;
public float jumpForce = 50;
public bool isGrounded;
bool jumpInput = false;
public LayerMask groundMask;
public Transform groundCheck1;
public Transform groundCheck2;


void FixedUpdate()
{
    Movements();
}

 void Movements()
{
    Vector2 velocity = rb.velocity;

    //If player jumps, it checks of the player is on ground and jumps if so
    jumpInput = Input.GetButton("Jump");
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapArea(new Vector2(groundCheck1.position.x, groundCheck1.position.y),
    new Vector2(groundCheck2.position.x, groundCheck2.position.y), groundMask);
    if (jumpInput && isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = jumpForce;
    }

    //This gets the movement bottons moves toward the direction player is going
    xMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    velocity.x = xMovement * speed;
    rb.velocity = velocity;

    rb.velocity = velocity;
}
```

Comment: It may be related that your Input.GetButton and Input.GetAxis calls are inside FixedUpdate method. Try moving those 2 lines in the Update method. The reason is that input is internally resfreshed in sync with Update and not FixedUpdate. Another thing is to try GetButtonDown instead of GetButton. GetButton is triggered for the full duration of the button hold, while GetButtonDown only at the moment of pressing.

Comment: @Nikaas Thanks that does improve it but not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an issue with your ground check. Expose the isgrounded variable in the editor and make sure it functions properly true when grounded and false in the air. I also had this issue a while ago.